# I want to compare the user input from my form to the queried data. but I want it not to be case sensitive. how do I do that?

Tags: android

/**compares the values of txtOrigin 
                and txtDestination to the query 
                variables assuming it matches*/

```
                if((origin.getText().toString().matches(queryOrigin))
                        && (destination.getText().toString().matches(queryDestination)))
                {
                //proceed to route found layout
                    Intent openRouteFound = new Intent("com.icommute.feu.RouteFound");
                    startActivity(openRouteFound);
                }

            /**compares the values of txtOrigin 
            and txtDestination to the query 
            variables assuming it doesn't match*/
                else
                {
                //proceed to no routes found layout
                    Intent openNoRoute = new Intent("com.icommute.feu.NoRoute");
                    startActivity(openNoRoute);
                }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try that:

```
 if((origin.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(queryOrigin))
      && (destination.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(queryDestination)))
 {
    ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

use .equalsIgnoreCase()  method 
eg:

```
if((origin.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(queryOrigin))
                    && (destination.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(queryDestination)))
            {
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`origin.getText().toString().matches("(?i)" + queryOrigin)`.

This will make regex `CASE_INSENSITIVE`